Typescript not recognising type of tuple
I have this sample code. The first console.log is considered valid by typescript, but when I extract the status check to a function, it doesn't recognise that resource is always available. It gives a 'resource' is possibly 'undefined'.(18048) error.
See playground
enum Status {
  Fetching,
  Available,
  Error
}

type Resource = Record<string, string>

type Available = [Resource, Status.Available];
type NotAvailable = [undefined, Status.Fetching | Status.Error];

const isAvailableStatus = (status: Status) => status === Status.Available;

const getResource = (): Available | NotAvailable => {
  return [undefined, Status.Fetching];
}

const [resource, resourceStatus] = getResource();

if (resourceStatus === Status.Available) {
  console.log(resource.test);
}

if (isAvailableStatus(resourceStatus)) {
  console.log(resource.test);
}

My real life problem is more complex, so it makes sense to extract the isAvailableStatus check. Of course I can add a bang to resource!, but I don't get why it's not working without it.
Any way to make this work?

You could either go with if (isAvailableStatus(resource, resourceStatus) && resource) or use refactor your logic e. g. with a type guard as shown in this playground. Does that answer your question? If so, I'll write up an answer.

Right now you can't make it work; it's a missing feature to use a type guard function to narrow a discriminant, as described in ms/TS#45770. This was going to be addressed in TS5.5 but the change was backed out, so for now it's not possible without some kind of workaround (such as doing a direct check on resourceStatus). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining further; if not, what am I missing?

I think that explains it @jcalz, thanks!

What you're doing isn't currently possible in TypeScript. You'll need to work around it by doing a direct check or some other refactoring.

Currently (as of TypeScript 5.4) the type of
const isAvailableStatus = (status: Status) => status === Status.Available;

is
const isAvailableStatus: (status: Status) => boolean

which has no implication whatsoever on the type of status.  You really want isAvailableStatus to be a custom type guard function whose return type is the type predicate status is Status.Available.  You can annotate that yourself, or wait until TypeScript 5.5 when type predicates will be inferred:
const isAvailableStatus = (status: Status): status is Status.Available =>
  status === Status.Available;

Now when you call isAvailableStatus(x) and it returns true, x will be narrowed from Status to Status.Available.
Alas, this will still not behave the way you want:
if (isAvailableStatus(resourceStatus)) {
  resourceStatus // const resourceStatus: Status.Available 
  console.log(resource.test); // still error 
}


And that's a missing feature. You're trying to treat the tuple [resource, resourceStatus] as a destructured discriminated union, where checking the discriminant resourceStatus has an implication on the type of resource.
This works when you check directly. But type guard functions do not have this effect; they will narrow the discriminant without affecting the rest of the union. There is a request at microsoft/TypeScript#45770 to address this, and it was even briefly fixed in microsoft/TypeScript#57358, but this fix was reverted in microsoft/TypeScript#57750 because it caused other issues.  So for now you cannot effectively "extract" the check of a discriminant to a type guard function.
Playground link to code

It's the destructuring moment const [resource, resourceStatus] = getResource(); when TypeScript loses the discriminated union understanding.
If you don't destructure and use index access, it works fine (See playground).
My mental model of this is that when you destructure a tuple of type Tuple into individual fields, the fields are no longer part of the tuple.
So in your example, that would mean that const [resource, resourceStatus] = getResource(); is analogous to:
const tuple = getResource();
const resource = tuple[0]; // Resource | undefined
const status = tuple[1]; // Status


The strange thing is that this was working:
  console.log(resource.test);
}```

So the destructuring itself is not the issue.
